# Are there any references to Prequel Trilogy specific content in Rogue One?

Tags: star-wars, rogue-one

Obviously, there's plenty of references to Original Trilogy in Rogue One (duh!)

**Are there any references to Prequel Trilogy specific content in Rogue One?**

Answer (score 19):

Indeed there are. These are all the prequel trilogy references to my knowledge.

- Coruscant makes a brief appearance in Jyn's flashback, the signature skyline can be seen in the background.
- Vader's lair is also confirmed to be on the planet Mustafar itself. (Confirmed by LFL Creative / Story Development Executive Pablo Hidalgo)
- A Clone Turbo/Juggernaut tank (seen in *Revenge of the Sith*) is shown as Jyn's prisoner transport.

[image: Clone Turbo/Juggernaut tank]

- Jimmy Smits and Genevieve O’Reilly both reprise their prequel roles as Bail Organa and Mon Mothma respectively.
- Bail Organa mentions the Clone Wars, which was briefly mentioned in Ep. 4, and unfolded from Ep. 2 to 3.
- Saw Gerrera, while not necessarily a Prequel **Trilogy** character, is a prequel trilogy era character created by George Lucas who made his debut in *The Clone Wars* animated series.

Comment: Jyn supposedly has a doll of an opee sea killer (from The Phantom Menace). I would go to the Wiki to get an exact list.

Answer (score 2):

Off the top of my head:

- Bail Organa, and the actor who played him
- (Possibly) the planet Mustafar (if that's where Vader's castle is)
- Coruscant (though only see briefly, in the flashback to Jyn's childhood in their apartment there)

Comment: Just confirmed [it's Mustafar](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/147605/62709). Jimmy Smits reprises his role as Bail Organa.

Comment: The Death Star itself, since we see a design for it in Attack of the Clones, and the skeleton of it in Revenge of the Sith.

Comment: @CBredlow But the Death Star wasn't prequel *specific*. Indeed, in the prequels it was a reference to the originals.